# resolve implicit for "A with B" based on user defined implicits for "A" and "B"

Tags: scala, types, implicit, phantom-types, union-types

In an effort to make domain object states explicit through phantom type parameters instead of separate domain types, I came up with a model such as this:

```
sealed trait State

sealed trait Verified extends State

sealed trait Contactable extends State

class Name[+S <: State](val name: String)

class User[S <: State] {
  def state(implicit n: Name[S]): String = n.name
}

implicit def verifiedName: Name[Verified] = new Name[Verified](name = "verified")
implicit def contactableName: Name[Contactable] = new Name[Contactable](name = "contactable")
implicit def nameAB[A <: State, B <: State](implicit s1: Name[A], s2: Name[B]): Name[A with B] = 
    new Name[A with B](name = s1.name concat " & " concat s2.name)

//client code
new User[Verified].state //Check!
new User[Contactable].state //Check!
new User[Contactable with Verified].state //Epic Fail!
//Error:(20, 38) diverging implicit expansion for type
// A$A516.this.Name[A$A516.this.Contactable with A$A516.this.Verified]
//starting with method nameAB in class A$A516
//new User[Contactable with Verified].state;}
```

What I want to achieve in general is automatic composition of behavior for commutative operations. In this case I need the `state` method of `User` with state `Contactable with Verified` to be "contactable & verified" or maybe even "verified & contactable". Scala's type system is all too much for me atm. So I can't figure out the problem. If solvable how can I do it? if not what's the reason?

Comment: I'd recommend case classes, less `new` noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think you are conflating notions of implicit resolution with phantom types. Deriving implicits for compound types from their simpler variants is a fairly well documented procedure, either you encode the record type as `HList` and derive as HList or you resort to implicit macros, which in effect does the same thing without the shapeless sugar.

Phantom types are about statically(at compile time) "mutating" the type argument on a class to encode some state in compile time, and it's generally not mixed with implicits like you suggest. What I mean is this:

```
trait State
trait Contacted extends State
trait Verifiable extends State


class Builder[C <: State, V <: State] {
  // In here I statically alter the signature of `Builder`
  // telling the compiler a call to `addContact`
  // will alter the type arg to the value of `Contacted`
  def addContact: Builder[Contacted, V]
  def verify(input: Whatever)(
    implicit ev: C =:= Contacted
  ): Builder[Contacted, Verifiable] = ???
}
```

In the above scenario, the compiler would now prevent you from calling `verifiable` before you `addContact`. And any later user of this method, if say you were building a framework, would get a compile time error if they tried to do something deemed invalid.

So the trick is not to try to unify the types per say, although you could, it's likely adding more downstream complexity than you think. With phantom types, you generally have "one per state".

Comment: could you also please provide an example which solves my problem using the HLists or implicit macro technique you mentioned?

Comment: @shayan No time on my hands sadly, and that's a very long topic that you will need to learn. If I help you'll need to give me a billing address :)

Comment: implicit macros are far less documented and esoteric, so you will need to invest quite a bit of time there.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution In my case where achieving the composition is the main goal replacing the `A with B` with `(A,B)` to express composition solves the problem:

```
sealed trait State

trait Verified extends State

trait Contactable extends State

class Name[S](val name: String)

class User[S] {
  def state(implicit n: Name[S]): String = n.name
}

implicit def aName: Name[Verified] = new Name[Verified](name = "verified")
implicit def bName: Name[Contactable] = new Name[Contactable](name = "contactable")
implicit def nameAB[A, B](implicit s1: Name[A], s2: Name[B]): Name[(A, B)] =
  new Name[(A, B)](name = s1.name concat " & " concat s2.name)

//client code
new User[Verified].state //Check!
new User[Contactable].state //Check!
new User[(Contactable, Verified)].state // Check!
```

from this point on other implicits could be defined for cases of `Tuple3, Tuple4 , ...` or use nested `tuple2`s to extend composition.
I have yet no answer regarding how the same could be achieved for the case of `A with B`